# How to solve react ionic capacitor status bar problem

Tags: ios, reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using react ionic capacitor for ios app.
I have problems in status bar.
My application covers all screen and status bar.
Is there any way for app not to cover status bar region?